Turn 30 amp line, 10/2 into a sub panel with 30 amp main and 2 120v lines
I have a 10/2 line running into my garage that was used for a welder. Can i turn that into a 30amp sub panel with 2 120v lines for outlets and lights?

Is that line 120V or 240V?

Maybe. 10/2 for a welder usually means two hots and a ground, commonly in the form of a black and white conductor with a bare wire. For a sub panel you need a minimum of a hot wire, neutral, and ground. This means you have enough wire to install a 120V single phase load center like the QO35FM30TTS and then hang two 120V circuits off it. This will only be possible if they fit in a 30A load calculation, so you can't plan to install two 120V 20A baseboard heaters or something like that, but it will be fine for tools. If you need 240V you will have to run a four wire cable.

OP will also need to remove the white hot from the feed breaker and turn the white into neutral again.

What's a white hot?

@Huesmann  The white wire used as a hot wire on devices not needing the neutral.  Heaters/welders/hot water heaters that use 240v but no neutral.  Saves buying an /3 cable if the third wire is not needed.  Also used on older switch loops, till people wanted to use smart switches.

Using that travel-trailer panel is IMO silly unless wall space is severely constrained. It's more expensive than a 6-space panel (same three spaces usable if you don't bother with a jumper and just feed one bus), or the same price as a 12-space panel (at least twice as many spaces usable). Using a regular two-bus panel also gives you the ability to upgrade to a two-leg feed later without having to spend even more money replacing the panel.

I agree with @nobody about the trailer panel. Sub-panels do not require a main since they are protected by the breaker feeding the panel. The main would not be required but may be desired for the convenience of turning off all the circuits at once. I would get the 6 space panel and be careful how much you load the circuits since it is only a 30 amp feeder.

Sure, a regular subpanel with both sides of the split fed off the feeder works fine as well. There's a lot of ways to slice this, I went with the cleanest example. Land your wires, add your circuits, done.

Since you only have a 10/2 feeder, you will need to wire a 120V panel.
This can be done with any common 240V panel, simply by splitting the single 120V wire to both hot terminals.  In fact my PC is being powered by that setup right now!  Now you have a true single-phase 120V-only panel.
Note that the main lugs in a panel are NOT rated for double-tap (2 wires under the lug) so you cannot land on one lug with a jumper to the other lug.  You must either pigtail (3 wires: supply and 2 pigtails); or get lucky with panel layout and run a hot wire through main lug #1 enroute to main lug #2, stripping insulation just where it's under the lug.

I agree. The 2 wire rule under a main lug is probably violated a fair amount but if you are being inspected with a sharp inspector they will gig you on this.
